# How can I use existing database in SERENE Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, rad, serenity-platform

I already have a database in SQL Server 2019 express and I would love to be able to use it in SERENE, how should I do it?

Comment: Just run the sergen on the tables, no need of migrations to be written as your database is ready

Answer (score 0):

The Migration helper checks, if the database of the connection string exists. if yes  data for migration will not be executed. Switch of this check in Line 205 in file Datamigrations.cs of :

```
            if (!isOracle && cs.ConnectionString.IndexOf(typeof(DataMigrations).Namespace +
                    @"_" + databaseKey + "_v1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
            {
//                SkippedMigrations = true;
//                return;
            }
```